# Remove click event on last item in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have an ng-repeat which looks like the following:

```
<ol>
    <li class="pointer node-name" ng-click="myClick(node)" ng-repeat="node in myArray">{{node.name}}</li>
</ol>
```

This is great and gives me an `<ol>` with `<li>`'s generated from `myArray`.

However, I want the last item in my `ng-repeat` to not have the `ng-click` event, or at least have it disabled.
For example:

```
<ol>
     <li class="pointer node-name" ng-click="myClick(node)" ng-repeat="node in myArray">Step 1</li>
     <li class="pointer node-name" ng-click="myClick(node)" ng-repeat="node in myArray">Step 2</li>
     <li class="pointer node-name" ng-click="myClick(node)" ng-repeat="node in myArray">Step 3</li>
     <li class="pointer node-name" ng-click="myClick(node)" ng-repeat="node in myArray">Step 4</li>
     <li class="pointer node-name" ng-repeat="node in myArray">Step 5</li>
    </ol>
```

Is this even possible? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$last`-Property within the `ngRepeat` to check if it is the last element. Then just place a condition inside your clickhandler...

```
<li class="pointer node-name" ng-click="myClick(node, $last)" ng-repeat="node in myArray">Step 5</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $index to see with index of the loop into myArray, [0 .. n-1].  And then when $index == myArray.length -1 you can disable the ng-click.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy enough to disable it.

```
<ol>
    <li class="pointer node-name" ng-click="myClick(node)" ng-disabled="$last" ng-repeat="node in myArray">{{node.name}}</li>
</ol>
```

or check if the index is equal to the length of the array minus 1 (last element)

```
<ol>
    <li class="pointer node-name" ng-click="myClick(node)" ng-disabled="$index === myArray.length - 1" ng-repeat="node in myArray">{{node.name}}</li>
</ol>
```